# Get instance property instead of undefined method

Tags: crystal-lang

```
class Place
  @description = "Default place"

  def initialize(x : Int32, y : Int32, description : String)
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @description = description

    puts "Description of this place is: #{description}"
  end
end



require "./browser-game/*"
require "./places/*"

module Browser::Game
  # TODO Put your code here
  place = Place.new 2, 3, "Yay new description"

  puts place.description
  puts "End of the program"
end
```

I receive this error:

> Error in browser-game.cr:8: undefined method 'description' for Place
>
> ```
> puts place.description
>            ^~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Comment: I like your coding setup

Comment: @LucaAngioloni thanks! Highly recommend Cathode terminal app for Mac with sounds from Alien (first movie)

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
class Place
  getter :description
  @description = "Default place"

  def initialize(x : Int32, y : Int32, description : String)
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @description = description

    puts "Description of this place is: #{description}"
  end
end
```

`getter` is used to give access to the read property from an instance. `setter` is for setting. Without this, the compiler will try to access the method since you did not give access to the property.

Comment: You can directly write `getter description = "Default place"`